# Safari animate.css infinite bounce on hover issue - it won't stop

Tags: css, safari, css-transitions, animate.css

Basically I have a div, which i have set up some css3 animation using the animate.css library. I want to make the child element bounce on hover. However on safari, it won't stop bouncing once you have stopped hovering. But it works fine on chrome, firefox?

```
<div class="animated-hover-child animated">
   <div class="portal-icon bounce">
      <img src="" alt="">
   </div>
   <div class="portal-title">
      <h3> Find a Distributor </h3>
   </div>
</div>
```

We want the portal-icon to bounce on hover of the parent div...
CSS:

```
.animated-hover-child:hover > div {
-webkit-animation-duration: 1s;
animation-duration: 1s;
-webkit-animation-fill-mode: both;
animation-fill-mode: both;
-webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}
.animated-hover:hover {
-webkit-animation-duration: 1s;
animation-duration: 1s;
-webkit-animation-fill-mode: both;
animation-fill-mode: both;
-webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}
.animated {
-webkit-animation-duration: 1s;
animation-duration: 1s;
-webkit-animation-fill-mode: both;
animation-fill-mode: both;
}
@-webkit-keyframes bounce {
0%, 20%, 53%, 80%, 100% {
-webkit-transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.215, 0.610, 0.355, 1.000);
transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.215, 0.610, 0.355, 1.000);
-webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
}
40%, 43% {
-webkit-transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.755, 0.050, 0.855, 0.060);
transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.755, 0.050, 0.855, 0.060);
-webkit-transform: translate3d(0, -30px, 0);
transform: translate3d(0, -30px, 0);
}
70% {
-webkit-transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.755, 0.050, 0.855, 0.060);
transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.755, 0.050, 0.855, 0.060);
-webkit-transform: translate3d(0, -15px, 0);
transform: translate3d(0, -15px, 0);
}
90% {
-webkit-transform: translate3d(0,-4px,0);
transform: translate3d(0,-4px,0);
}
}
@keyframes bounce {
0%, 20%, 53%, 80%, 100% {
-webkit-transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.215, 0.610, 0.355, 1.000);
transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.215, 0.610, 0.355, 1.000);
-webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
-ms-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
}
40%, 43% {
-webkit-transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.755, 0.050, 0.855, 0.060);
transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.755, 0.050, 0.855, 0.060);
-webkit-transform: translate3d(0, -30px, 0);
-ms-transform: translate3d(0, -30px, 0);
transform: translate3d(0, -30px, 0);
}
70% {
-webkit-transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.755, 0.050, 0.855, 0.060);
transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.755, 0.050, 0.855, 0.060);
-webkit-transform: translate3d(0, -15px, 0);
-ms-transform: translate3d(0, -15px, 0);
transform: translate3d(0, -15px, 0);
}
90% {
-webkit-transform: translate3d(0,-4px,0);
-ms-transform: translate3d(0,-4px,0);
transform: translate3d(0,-4px,0);
}
}
.bounce {
-webkit-animation-name: bounce;
animation-name: bounce;
-webkit-transform-origin: center bottom;
-ms-transform-origin: center bottom;
transform-origin: center bottom;
}
```